# Splash screen look different on device vs storyboard

Tags: xcode, react-native

I'm trying to make a splash screen on ios, but weird is, it fit perfectly when using storyboard but not fit when using simulator or real device

It show perfect on storyboard
[image]

But small in real or simulator
[image]

Please help, i don't know what going on

Comment: Did you add constraints?

Comment: try set constraints to 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set Top, Bottom, Leading, and Trailing constraints to 0. Don't Give Height and Width to it, just constraints are enough.

[image]